# Отключить автоматическое изменение размера окон в Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Я тут пытаюсь удобно организовать рабочее пространство в xcode, но проблема заключается в том что он автоматически выставляет размер окон в Assistant, стоит лишь мне переключиться на редактирование другого файла. Т.е я хочу чтобы одно окно занимало например 80% экрана, а другое 20%, но xcode делит экран 50 на 50. Возможно ли как-то это отключить или настроить? На скриншотах два наглядных примера того как я хочу сделать, и как получается в итоге. Помогите пожалуйста, и не ругайтесь сильно если что-то не так, это мой первый вопрос на stackoverflow))
[image: Хочу так]
[image: После переключения вкладки становится так]

Comment: Вы можете открыть файл (или сториборд) в отдельном окне и уже эти окна разделить, как вам нужно. Если я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите :)

Comment: @NSA-bot, Ну, это довольно интересный способ решить эту проблему, спасибо)) Но странно что проблема вообще существует. Тот же VS Code не пытается решать за пользователя какое расположение окон будет для него удобнее, а просто делает так, как ему сказали. Ну ладно, будем привыкать))

Comment: Да там много странного в этом икскоде, но уж как есть :))